# MYSQL get common ids from multiple query results

Tags: mysql

I have 3 queries that give me 3 results

```
SELECT group_concat(cna_id) FROM `cna_filters` where filter_type=1 and filter_id in(1,6,10) and is_checked=1 group by filter_type,cna_id
```

Result - 42,43,44,45

```
SELECT group_concat(cna_id) FROM `cna_filters` where filter_type=2 and filter_id in(8) and is_checked=1 group by filter_type,cna_id
```

Result - 42,43

```
SELECT group_concat(cna_id) FROM `cna_filters` where filter_type=3 and filter_id in(11) and is_checked=1 group by filter_type,cna_id
```

Result - 42,43,44,45

I want an output of common ids from above 3 results like this

Result = 42,43

I have tried Union but did not work.

Comment: what you have tried for this..?

Comment: I have tried this (SELECT cna_id FROM `cna_filters` where filter_type=1 and filter_id in(1,6,10) and is_checked=1 group by filter_type,cna_id) UNION
(SELECT cna_id FROM `cna_filters` where filter_type=2 and filter_id in(8) and is_checked=1 group by filter_type,cna_id) UNION (SELECT cna_id FROM `cna_filters` where filter_type=3 and filter_id in(11) and is_checked=1 group by filter_type,cna_id

Comment: Your queries don't make sense. If you group by cna_id, you can only get one cna_id with group_concat(cna_id). So you can just as well write the first query as `SELECT cna_id FROM cna_filters where filter_type=1 and filter_id in(1,6,10) and is_checked=1`. Same for the other queries.

Comment: Ok let me try this  SELECT cna_id FROM cna_filters where filter_type=1 and filter_id in(1,6,10) and is_checked=1 @ThorstenKettner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the intersection of the three data sets. This would be very simple, if MySQL supported standard SQL's `INTERSECT`.

But this can also be solved with conditional aggregation to check that a `cna_id` exists in all three data sets (and the table must be read just once with this method):

```
select cna_id
from cna_filters
where is_checked=1
group by cna_id
having sum( filter_type = 1 and filter_id in (1, 6, 10) ) > 0
   and sum( filter_type = 2 and filter_id = 8 ) > 0
   and sum( filter_type = 3 and filter_id = 11 ) > 0;
```

Comment: Oops, sorry, that must be `HAVING` of course, not `WHERE`. I've updated my answer.

Comment: I also didn't see that these are different filter types, so I had to update the answer again.

Comment: Thanks @Thorsten It Worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT group_concat(cna_id) FROM `cna_filters`
WHERE group_concat(cna_id) = 'object1'
UNION
SELECT group_concat(cna_id) FROM `cna_filters`
WHERE group_concat(cna_id) = 'object2'
UNION
SELECT group_concat(cna_id) FROM `cna_filters`
WHERE group_concat(cna_id) = 'object3'
```